# split in java for csv file with random content for last field

Tags: split

Split in java for CSV file with last field any content including the splitter symbol.
sample input line.

2010-10-06 09:02:10,498 [RenderingQueue] INFO  [RenderingQueue]: Waiting for next command...
.
..

So far i used a blank as separator (6 fields, 5 separations)
.
I thought separating on blank that was fine untill the last field (6) 
After the  - -     [RenderingQueue]:   ----  ( = field 5)  a field 6 should contain everything afterwards. 
In this sample line field 6 contains "Waiting for next command..." .
That field 6 can contain blanks , semicolon, double point,words , :  etc.. of any length .
I look for split statement to specify 5 splits and everything afterwards in the field 6 .
thanks beforehand.

my code :

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
```

//
        // split up the line into an array of 1 dimension
                    String [] splittedline  = new String [6];

```
                splittedline = line.split(" ",5);
                //
                // show content in console (for test purposes)
                //
                for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
                System.out.println(splittedline[i]);
                }
                //
```

My code causes error :
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
    at project1.readlogbook.main(readlogbook.java:74)